# How to disable vibration in Google Keep Reminders?

Tags: notifications, vibration, google-keep

Every time I get a reminder in Google Keep I hear the notification sound and the phone vibrates.

I'd like to hear the notification sound but I don't want the phone to vibrate.

How can I disable the vibration?